# http status 200 200 (not 200 ok) in angular application

Tags: http

I have an angular application runs okey but currently I am getting http status `200 200` for one of my service. Yap you herd right `200 200` not `200 ok`

Normally the status code `200 ok` ([detail about status 200 ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200)) is the actual response I suppose to get but its `200 200`. I am not sure if its angular problem or server problem. Even if its the problem or not. Actually its taking into the infinite loop and application breaks.

[image]

Comment: This is a server problem.

Comment: But I did not see anywhere what that status is. there is no such http status i found

Comment: server ofc, how could angular change the display result of the chrome console?

Comment: This status does not exists, the server is not sending the status correctly..

Comment: yes, this is a server error and not angular problem. 200 200 is coming due to some tomcat problem. working to fix this

Comment: i never see this http status, its interesting to know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the `tomcat` and `nginx` server. Somehow both the servers were returning status 200 and by combined both of the header, it will getting `200 200`.

That is why from the UI angular end it was unable to understand the status and creating problem by infinite loop.

Comment: Aniruddha Das how did you fix this.  I'm having the exact same issue.  Angular is caling a web service which in turn is calling another web service and I'm getting 200 200.

Comment: I'm working with an API that's doing this. Looks like they have tomcat and apache though. How exactly is an infinite loop created, though?

I don't think there's anything we as a client can do. Any suggestions on what to tell them?